# Cannot find module after change directory

Tags: python, python-os, python-importlib

So I have to create a run folder, that is, a folder which has a bunch of python files which I need to run. I am able to create this folder with ease and all the files are there. However, when I try to run the files using `importlib`, python is not about to find it.

I want to make sure that the code running is, in fact, the run folder code, hence I change the directory to location of the run folder.

```
abs_path = os.path.abspath("{}".format(run_location))
os.chdir(abs_path)
files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)]
print(files)
try:
    driver_module = importlib.import_module("main_driver.py")
    driver_module.main(config, logger)
except Exception as e:
    logger.error("error", str(e))
    finish_fail(config, logger)
finish_success(config, logger)
```

In the above example, I just want to run `main_driver.py`. The output from the above is:

```
['PrepareDataframe.py', 'categorical_encoding.py', 'extra_files.zip', 'build_features.py', 'spot_extractor.py', 'dev.ini', 'featuriser.py', 'main_driver.py', 'time_features_extract.py']
```

Clearly, `main_driver.py` is within the current working directory but I get this error.

```
No module named 'main_driver'
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./utils/submit.py", line 292, in <module>
    driver_module = importlib.import_module("main_driver")
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main_driver'
```

Comment: Don't use the `.py` extension on the filename.  Just use `import_module('main_driver')`.

Comment: Still gives the same issue `driver_module = importlib.import_module("main_driver")`

Comment: That's odd; it works for me.  Can you try a smaller example script that leaves out all the chdir stuff and just has `importlib.import_module('main_driver')`, and place it in the same directory as that module?

Comment: @BryceRamgovind Try importing it without the `.py` extension. `driver_module = importlib.import_module("build_features")`

Comment: @lahsuk still gives that import error even without the '.py' extension. The error disappears when I run it directly from the run folder and not chdir.

Comment: @JohnGordon the error disappears when I run it from the run folder directly without chdir

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This appears to be a `PYTHONPATH` issue.

When you run the Python interactive interpreter, the first item in `sys.path` is an empty string, which effectively means "the current directory".  So any time you try to import a module, it will look in the current directory first.

However, if you run `python myscript.py`, this is not the case -- the first item in `sys.path` is the actual directory you were in when you ran the script.  So, if you use `os.chdir()` to change the current directory, the new current directory isn't in `sys.path`, and so `import_module('foo')` fails because it's not found.

If you want to mimic the interactive python behavior of always looking in the current directory for modules, add `sys.path.insert(0, '')` to your script.

Comment: worked like a charm, thank you.

are there any better ways to approach this? for my research I'm often building a self contained module where I sometimes run files inside folders of the module so I have to move the cwd up a folder or two, it's not the cleanest of code but it works, I'm just wondering if there are better or cleaner approaches.